# How I can add SOAP Service header

Tags: c#, api, web-services, soap, soap-client

I'm using SOAP web service in my project, Service Provide support told me send us username and password in header tag, How I can add header username and password with C#.Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

We know nothing about your code, but the header itself could look something like this:

```
<soap:Header>
  <Auth xmlns="https://soapAdressGoesHere.com">
    <username>USER</username>
    <password>PASS</password>
  </Auth>
</soap:Header>
```